# Drag and Drop Functionality using JavaScript for an email client application

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need a drop and drag functionality for my email client application.

I have some e-mails in my Inbox, I want them to move to my user defined folders by using drag and drop functionality by using JavaScript.

Looking forward for your response.

Comment: And i would like to know the winning lottery number for the 1,000,000 jackpot! Someone tell me that!!

Comment: can people explain why this is getting voted down? at least so members like myself can understand why?

Comment: Looks like an assignment rather than a problem

Comment: Won't a down vote make more sense if supported with a reason. Learning why the question was voted down would definitely help a newbie. After all, this indeed is an open forum.

Comment: @Pavan yes you're exactly right - this question is probably worth a downvote but if the reasons are not explained, the asker won't have any idea how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out JQuery, a very nice wrapper for Javascript with many nice UI plugins, including drag and drop.
This page has tons of drag and drop demos. You can scroll through and pick the plugin that you like --> [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/drag-drop-jquery-plugins/)

And particularly, this plugin is probably exactly what you're looking for http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Answer (score 1):

YUI has some drag-and-drop APIs. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/dragdrop/